# How to disable D9002 for VS2012 and above?

Tags: visual-studio, xsd, msbuild, compiler-warnings

We distribute Visual Studio 2010 project files. Its our minimum platform requirement for the MSBuild-style project files. Users are expected to upgrade it as necessary. The project also has each configuration set to `/arch:SSE2` as a default. Users are expected to upgrade it as necessary.

We are experiencing a D9002 dirty compile under Visual Studio 2012 and above due to use of `/arch:SSE2` as a minimum platform architecture (related, [/arch setting for VS2010 - VS2015](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39824455)). We added the following to our project file to squash the warning:

```
<!-- Visual Studio 2012 dirty compile due to use of SSE2 -->
<ItemDefinitionGroup Condition="'$(VisualStudioVersion)'>='11.0'">
  <ClCompile>
    <DisableSpecificWarnings>9002;%(DisableSpecificWarnings)</DisableSpecificWarnings>
  </ClCompile>
</ItemDefinitionGroup>
```

The above code runs fine on Visual Studio 2010. Under Visual Studio 2012 it creates more noise:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: cryptest, Configuration: Release x64 ------
1>cl : Command line warning D9014: invalid value '9002' for '/wd'; assuming '4999'
1>cl : Command line warning D9002: ignoring unknown option '/arch:SSE2'
```

Visual Studio complains it does not know what the warning is, and then it issues the warning. You can't make this stuff up...

We have an [SDLC](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735617228) and we follow [Microsoft's recommendations](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sdl/). We also take a firmer posture and make clean compiles a security gate because (1) it causes user hardships, and (2) it generates chatter on the mailing list and reports in the issue tracker.

How do we disable D9002 for VS2012 and above?

Comment: Have you considered working the other way around, i.e. not applying unknown compiler options depending on the VS version? (which is also cleaner as it doesn't introduce the warning in the first place)

Comment: Did you try the steps here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj715718(v=vs.110).aspx?